# Google Chrome Extension that Hides my IP

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Is there a Google Chrome extension that allows me to hide my current IP ( I'm located in a country outside the US) and make it into a US IP?

The reason I want to do this is because I want to be able to buy digital content that are only available to the US( such as Hulu TV shows) people. And these websites would check my IP address before I buy and download. I want to bypass this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Be aware, if you use one of those services, the proxy provider may read and manipulate all your requests.**

**The proxy will redirect your traffic and if you don't use an encrypted communication channel (HTTPS, encrypted emails) the owner of the proxy can collect all your traffic. It's like he is your ISP.**

---

Try TOR

http://www.torproject.org/

Its not a chrome extension but it hides your ip with all your browsers.

You will need to set your exit node to a american server.

http://www.ghacks.net/2008/01/29/configure-tor-to-use-a-specific-country-as-an-exit-node/

OR

**HideMyAss** chrome extension for the easy way

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cmgnmcnlncejehjlnhaglpnoolgbflbd

Comment: what do you mean by proxy provider may manipulate my request? Does it mean that anything I transmit to the web server will be collected?

Comment: technically yes. I edited my answer for more info.

Answer (score 4):

The **BEST** Chrome extension (and indeed far superior way to anything else i've tried) to accomplish what you need is called **[Media Hint](https://mediahint.com/)**. All you need to do is to install the extension and thats it. There are no settings to configure, as it will automatically detect when you visit such a website. Enjoy !!

It is also available as a Firefox Add-on.

An alternative to Media Hint, but also available as a Chrome extension is **Hola Unblocker**:

http://hola.org/unblocker.html

This is also available as a Firefox extension, as well as on other platforms.